# What is function stack-full in algorithm?

Tags: stack, stack-trace

Here is algorithm of stack, I want to know what can be function stack-full, here? Or something like it about queue.

```
Procedure ADD(item,a,n,top)
if(top>=n) then stack-full()
top++;
a(top) <-- 1
end
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: No language it's algorithm style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an abstract handler to handle a stack overflow. You are to decide what it should do: throw an exception or increase stack size.